# close request is not working on dialog box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

When an icon is clicked, a dialog box with form should appear to either add a tab or delete specific tab. I have used reactjs, redux and material-ui for components. 
I could show the dialog box when icon is clicked but when i click on cancel button, dialog box does not get close.

What should i do to resolve it?

Here is my code

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                  max_char: 32,
                  open: false,
                };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
  }

  handleClose = () => this.setState({ open: false });

  handleOpen = () => this.setState({ open: true });

  render() {
      return (
            <div>
                <Header
                      tab={this.state.tabs}
                      open={this.state.open}
                      handleClose={this.handleClose}
                      handleToggle={this.handleToggle}
                />
                <Content
                    handleOpen={this.handleOpen}
                    handleClose={this.handleClose}
                />
            </div>
      );
  }
}
```

**Header.js**

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    const tabs = _.map(this.props.tab, (tab) =>
         <span className="tab" key={tab.id}><a href="">{tab.description}</a></span>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar
            title={tabs}
            iconElementRight={navigation}
            onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.props.handleToggle}
            style={{ background: '#fff' }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    iconList: state.iconList
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    selectTabIcon
  }, dispatch);
}


const Content = (props) =>
    (
      <div className="content-section">
        <TabDialog />
      </div>
    );
```

**TabDialog.js**

```
class TabDialog extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                      open: false,
                    };
      }

      renderAddTab() {
        const actions = [
          <FlatButton
            label="Cancel"
            primary
            onTouchTap={this.props.createTab.close}
          />,
          <FlatButton
            label="Add Tab"
            primary
            keyboardFocused
            onTouchTap={this.props.createTab.close}
          />,
        ];
        return (
          <div className="device-action">
            <Dialog
                title="Add a Tab"
                actions={actions}
                modal={false}
                open={this.props.createTab.open}
                onRequestClose={this.props.createTab.close}
            >
            <div className="tab-name">
            <TextField
              floatingLabelText="Name"
              floatingLabelStyle={{ color: '#1ab394' }}
              floatingLabelFocusStyle={{ color: '#1db4c2' }}
              underlineStyle={{ borderColor: '#1ab394' }}
            />
            </Dialog>
          </div>
      );
      }

      renderDeleteTab() {
        const actions = [
          <FlatButton
            label="Cancel"
            primary
            onTouchTap={this.props.createTab.close}
          />,
          <FlatButton
            label="Delete"
            primary
            keyboardFocused
            onTouchTap={this.props.createTab.close}
          />,
        ];
        return (
        <div className="tab-action">
          <Dialog
              title="Delete"
              actions={actions}
              modal={false}
              open={this.props.createTab.open}
              onRequestClose={this.props.createTab.close} />
        </div>
      );
      }


      render() {
        const iconSelected = this.props.createTab;
        if (!iconSelected) {
          return (<div>Select</div>);
        }
        if (iconSelected === '1') {
          return (this.renderDeleteTab());
        }
        if (iconSelected === '2') {
          return (this.renderAddTab());
        }
    }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {
        iconList: state.iconList,
        createTab: state.createTab,
      };
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({
        addTab,
        selectTabIcon
      }, dispatch);
    }
```

**redux part**

```
export function selectTabIcon(selectTab) {
      console.log('selected', selectTab.target.id);
      return {
        type: 'TAB_ICON_SELECTED',
        id: selectTab.target.id,
        open: true,
        close: () => false
      };
    }

    switch (action.type) {
      case 'TAB_ICON_SELECTED':
        console.log('tab', action);
        return action;
```

open props accept boolean and onRequestClose and onTouchTap props accepts function.

Why is my code not working? How can i overcome this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. onRequestClose and onTouchTap both accepts function. They need open to be false. Why i failed is i passed false value to close flag instead to open.

Now i have created a new action creator where i have passed an action to close it by setting open payload to false

```
export function closeTabIcon() {
  return {
    type: 'CLOSE_ICON',
    open: false
  }
}

reducer will be something like this

   case 'CLOSE_ICON':
     return action.open
```

Now in the OnRequestProps i passed this.props.closetabIcon.

Answer (score 0):

The `onRequestClose` prop of `Dialog` takes a `function` not a `boolean`. So, you need to change the value of `this.props.createTab.open` to `false` inside that function. By this, the state will be changed by the redux and the value for `open` will be passed as `false`. This will close the Dialog.

Comment: Do you mean to say i change the value of open to false in my selectTabIcon function?

Comment: @milan yup, change the value to false

Comment: I changed the value of open from true to false and did not change the close value. I then passed this.props.createTab.open on open props and this.props.createTab.close on onRequestClose props. But to open a dialog, open props should get true as a value.

Comment: Can you please explain me a bit? It's not working that way.